# Django - Filter on many to many model

Tags: django-models

I have 2 models: Book, Author

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

and in admin :

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title')
    filter_horizontal = ('authors',)
```

**in admin** , I want to see only Authors that related to specified Book
not all Authors
(in add mode Authors must be empty)

AdminBook:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes, very much.